# Python tkinter: rows in frame hide after 1559 row

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on my first tkinter App and I met a problem I cannot solve myself. I load text labels through a loop, but rows after 1559 are hidden like below a layer. I can scroll down, but I cant see loaded rows. Have You met problem like mine before?

[Python problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKGJ3.png)

Comment: I highly recommend finding another way to display your information, such as pages of 20 or 50 rows each.

Comment: I fully agree with You. The problem is, that I need to show them on one page, it's essential for app's usability. Other possible solution I can consider is to show data in many collumns, what would result in very poor convenience of usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26547250/1832058

Comment: Are you using a frame embedded in a canvas? The canvas has a finite size.  Most likely, the height of the label times the number of rows is hitting that limit.

Comment: Are you creating a new label for each row? Do you want to present the data as a table? Might want to check out [Treeview widget](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html), it can be used to display data as a table.